# How to change the folder of Java binary in Flutter

Tags: java, flutter, system

In my project i need to keep my Java on ver.8, but suddenly, it was updated. I've tried to fix it, by playing with system variables, but I've found that my Flutter depends on some custom path to Java[image]

How can i change that?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've just reinstalled an AndroidStudio and now it's pointing to right destination

[image]